# why is BroadcastReceiver called twice from the OnPostExecute in asystask?

Tags: android

The Question is Simple that I created Broadcaster class in Fragrment class.
and call Asystask class for my perform.
After execute the class (on onPostExecute method), I send the Broadcaster with intent to Fragment class ONLY ONCE.

However, the result is I got into the OnReiver method 2 times.
(I verified by using Log that I got into the onPostExecute method and send the broadcaster once, But the OnReiver method triggered twice).
Anyone can give me help. It bugs me and wasted so much time.  Thank you

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment{ 

@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_panel, container, false);
      mContext = currentView.getContext();
      init();
      return currentView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(albumListBroadcaster, new IntentFilter(CommonUtilities.BROADCASTEROFALBUMTITLELIST));
  }

  private void init(){

      albumListBroadcaster = new AlbumListBroadcaster();

      setOnClickButtonsEvent();
      clearBtn();
  }

  public void setOnClickButtonsEvent(){
      //modifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new ModifyAccountBtnListener());
      modifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, WebActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
            }
        });
  }


   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == REQUESTCODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //sendBroadcaster();
                data = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(CommonUtilities.SHAREDPREFERENCEURL, 0);
                String usertToken = data.getString("userToken", "");
                String mobileUserId = data.getString("mobileUserId", "");
                String services = intentData.getStringExtra("servicesJSONArray");

                try {
                    JSONArray socialMedias = new JSONArray(services);
                    Log.d("socialMedias", socialMedias.toString());
                    clearBtn();
                    //JSONArray accountInfo = new JSONArray(services);
                    mDisplayPicOnAlbumFragment.onDisplayPicOnAlbumFragment(new JSONArray());
                    if(socialMedias.length() > 0){

                        totalArrayForAlbum = new JSONArray();
                        int lastNum = socialMedias.length();

                        for(int i = 0;i< lastNum;i++){
                            JSONObject one = socialMedias.getJSONObject(i);
                            String socialName = one.getString("service_display_name");
                            activateBtn(i,socialName);
                            String serviceName = one.getString("service_name");
                            Map <String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                            map.put("userToken", usertToken);
                            map.put("userId", mobileUserId);
                            map.put("serviceName", serviceName);
                            new RequestAlbums(map,getActivity()).execute(CommonUtilities.ALBUMLISTURL);

                        }
                    }else{
                        ArrayList<String> emptyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
                        emptyArr.add(getString(R.string.emptyList));
                        createMenu(emptyArr);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
}


public class AlbumListBroadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver{

    String title = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("OnRecive","i am here");

       } 
}


   public class RequestAlbums extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,String>{

private HttpEntity httpEntity;
private HttpGet httpGet;
private HttpClient httpClient;
private InputStream inputStream;
private HttpResponse httpResponse;
private Map<String,String> param;
private Context mContext;

public RequestAlbums(Map<String,String> param,Context c){
    this.param = param;
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-gworkenerated method stub
      Log.d("background", result);
      ArrayList<String> resultArr = getOnlyTitle(result);
      Intent intent = new Intent(CommonUtilities.BROADCASTEROFALBUMTITLELIST);
      intent.putStringArrayListExtra("titleList", resultArr);
      intent.putExtra("resultInfo", result);
      //intent.putExtra("titleList", resultArr.toString());

      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
      //super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... input) {

    ---
}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that you have your sendBroadcast() function being called in your onActivityResult?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(requestCode == REQUESTCODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            sendBroadcaster();
```

Comment: I am sorry  i tried to tailor to the code. and i didn't delete that.  that broadcast is for something else..

Comment: Also just deleted that 'sendBroadcaster()' code. it does same thing.